# sass - use abstract selectors or mixins/placeholder?

Tags: html, css

This might have been covered in another thread. I didn't find it though..

Today, with Sass I have 2 options of styling my website.
Lets see examples

### Example 1

```
<button class="button main center">Submit</button>
```

I have 3 classes, each is quite abstract.. collisions may occur. For example - bootstrap has a selector `.close`. It collided with my code on several projects.

### Example 2

```
<button class="submit-button">Submit</button>

.submit-button{
    @include button;
    @include main;
    @include center;
}
```

I can also do this with placeholder and extend, but the implementation is not relevant for the question.

In this method I have a more specific selector, and I reuse my css rules in my scss files.

## The question

Which should I use?

Is it just a matter of taste, or is there a technical reason to prefer one over the other?

One would require me to modify the html a lot, the other would require me to change CSS.
I tend to like changing my CSS better since it is not changing content (for me, all parts of html is considered content, metadata too), just style

As mentioned I am styling a website, and not developing a library like bootstrap to be used by others.

Answer (score 1):

Your first example:

```
<button class="button main center">Submit</button>
```

is wrong:

- `button` class is repeating the element itself. Do you have a `class="p"` for every paragraph, and a `class="li"` for every list item? What's the point?
- `main` is particularly unclear. Just by looking at the CSS, how would you be able to determine what's `main` is referring to?
- `center` is a wrong name for a class: `center` is a value, not a class name. Imagine you want your hyperlinks to be green. Would you do:

  ```css
  a {
      color: green;
  }
  ```

  or you'll create:

  ```css
  .green {
      color: green;
  }
  ```

  and then add `class="green"` to all your links, and then learn that the customer wants the links to be shown in orange now?

---

Consider a slightly improved example of a button which cancels an operation while being highlighted for some reason and shows an icon near the text. Should you do this:

```
<button class="cancel highlighted with-icon">Cancel</button>
```

or be more specific?

```
<button class="cancel-highlighted-with-icon">Cancel</button>
```

It all comes to how styles are used. For instance:

- Would it make sense to highlight buttons which are not cancel buttons?
- Is there an icon option for buttons which are not cancel buttons?

The first question would probably receive a positive answer, and the highlight style will probably be the same for any other type of button—submit button, ordinary button, save button, delete button—you name it. Therefore, it makes sense to keep a separate `.highlighted` style. To prevent collisions, it may be scoped to buttons: `button.highlighted`.

The second question, on the other hand, is less obvious. While submit buttons and save buttons and delete buttons could all have an icon, it might be that their style would be different every time; if all the style contains is the `background-image` property, by using `with-icon` class, you'll still have code duplication:

```css
.cancel {
    border: ...; border-radius: ...; padding: ...; }
.cancel.with-icon {
    background-image: ...; }
.save {
    border: ...; border-radius: ...; padding: ...; }
.save.with-icon {
    background-image: ...; }
...
```

However, what are the alternatives? Let's say you end up combining `cancel` class with `with-icon`. Now you have:

```css
.cancel {
    border: ...; border-radius: ...; padding: ...; }
.cancel-with-icon {
    border: ...; border-radius: ...; padding: ...; background-image: ...; }
.save {
    border: ...; border-radius: ...; padding: ...; }
.save-with-icon {
    border: ...; border-radius: ...; padding: ...; background-image: ...; }
```

with huge code duplication.

If this alone is not enough, there is another reason to keep `with-icon` separate. If you need to toggle icons on and off on the buttons, you can do it in a single method through jQuery if `with-icon` is an actual class. Otherwise, you'll be forced to create a map between `cancel` and `cancel-with-icon`, `save` and `save-with-icon`, and change those classes, which, while technically feasible, requires more code.

Comment: Thank you so much for your long and detailed answer. The example "main button center" is taken from bootstrap - "btn btn-primary center-block"